# Pattern Matching Function Call in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am originally posting the question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118849/pattern-matching-function-call-in-scala) but it seems to be not fitted there. I'll reask here. Please tell me if it's also not fit here, and where should I post this kind of question. Thanks.

I am a newbie in Scala and functional programming. I want to call a function several times, with combination of parameters based on two variables. Basically, What I am doing right now is this:

```
def someFunction(a: Int, b: Int): Future[Int] = ???

val value1 = true
val value2 = false

(value1, value2) match {
    case (true, true) =>
        val res1 = someFunction(0, 0)
        val res2 = someFunction(0, 1)
        val res3 = someFunction(1, 0)
        val res4 = someFunction(1, 1)

        for {
            r1 <- res1
            r2 <- res2
            r3 <- res3
            r4 <- res4
        } yield r1 + r2 + r3 + r4

    case (true, false) =>
        val res1 = someFunction(0, 0)
        val res2 = someFunction(1, 0)

        for {
            r1 <- res1
            r2 <- res2
        } yield r1 + r2

    case (false, true) =>
        val res1 = someFunction(0, 0)
        val res2 = someFunction(0, 1)

        for {
            r1 <- res1
            r2 <- res2
        } yield r1 + r2

    case (false, false) =>
        for { r1 <- someFunction(0, 0) } yield r1
}
```

I am not satisfied with the above code as it is repetitive and hard to read / maintain. Is there any better way I could do this? I've tried to search on how to combine function by pattern matching value like this, but finds nothing to work with. Looks like I don't know the right term for this.

Any help would be appreciated, and feel free to change the title if there's a better wording.

Thanks before :)

Comment: It seems like you want to generate the parameters for someFunction based on two booleans and sum all results. Is this correct?

Comment: @irundaia yes, I want to generate the parameter and combine the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easier way could be to pregenerate a sequence of argument tuples:

```
val arguments = for {
  arg1 <- 0 to (if (value1) 1 else 0)
  arg2 <- 0 to (if (value2) 1 else 0)
} yield (arg1, arg2)
```

Then you can combine function executions on the arguments with `Future.traverse` to get a `Future` of the sequence of results, and then `sum` the results:

```
Future.traverse(arguments)(Function.tupled(someFunction)).map(_.sum)
```

Comment: This is actually a cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem:

```
def someFunction(x: Int, y: Int): Future[Int] = ???
def someFunctionTupled: ((Int, Int)) => Future[Int] = (someFunction _).tupled // Same as someFunction but you can pass in a  tuple here

def genParamList(b: Boolean) = if (b)
  List(0, 1)
else
  List(0)

val value1 = true
val value2 = false

val l1 = genParamList(value1)
val l2 = genParamList(value2)

// Combine the two parameter lists by constructing the cartesian product
val allParams = l1.foldLeft(List[(Int, Int)]()){
  case (acc, elem) => acc ++ l2.map((elem, _))
}

allParams.map((someFunction _).tupled).sum
```

The above code will result in a `Future[Int]` which is the sum of all results of `someFunction` applied to the elements of the `allParams` list.